# Can GUID string be used as a folder name on a windows server

Tags: .net, guid

I would like to create folders dynamically on a windows web server to store uploaded files from client machines. I am planning to use GUID values, created as part of the asp.net membership module, as the folder names. Since the  chracters, / \ * ? < > |,  are not allowed in a windows folder name, I am wondering whether any of them will be part of a GUID and hence will cause issues.

Thanks

Comment: As a matter of fact there are usually dozens of folders with such names already on your system. Check out `C:\Windows\Installer` (adjust the Windows folder location as needed).

Comment: @skaffman: can you please explain why you added the .net tag? It really has nothing to do with any programming language or framework. This is about a file system and operating system.

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED: It is kind of particular to .NET as the "most usual string serialization of a GUID" might vary by platform. Who knows, maybe there's a platform out there that base64 encodes GUIDs when turning them into a string by default, thus making them invalid file names (due to the `/` character)

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED Because this is about .net-generated GUIDs, which are specific to that framework.

Comment: Hmm, I thought they are the common "Registry GUID format"? But anyway, thanks for the explanation. Guess it makes sense for others to find the question. Which the tags are all about. :)

Comment: -1 for not doing a basic reading on GUID first

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The string serialization used for GUIDs by .NET (as pointed out by [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/97af8hh4.aspx), which you might want to read next time before asking) consists only of hexadecimal numbers and dashes, so yes, you can safely use them as file or directory names.

Comment: +1 you were first. damned "human verification" dialogue every time I answer lately :^(

Answer (score 5):

A GUID can simply be stored as the hexadecimal digits, so no problem. Or you can also intersperse the segments with hyphens, still with no problem.

Comment: I suspected as much but didn't want to have to boot into Windows to test something I wasn't sure about

Comment: `C:\Windows\Installer` has plenty of folders with such names as soon as you install anything based on Windows Installer ... in case you can check the partition without rebooting :)

Comment: touche'. I see that now using 'locate {'